# Excel application flashing before hiding when using Application.Visible propety

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a Userform without opening excel application. After some searching, I found the codes to do that. It is working fine, however the Excel window always opens before it hides. Is there anyway to avoid flashing of the excel window so that only the userform shows up and nothing else. I have set the following code inside ThisWorkbook object in Excel VBA.

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()
  Application.Visible = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Uf_Randomizer.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Please help, Thanks in advance.

P.S- I am new to this

Comment: I assume this code runs when the workbook first opens which means the excel application has already opened before the script started. Add `MsgBox "Hello"` as the first line in the function. Excel will be visible before the MsgBox shows.

Comment: So, is there no work around to it ?

Comment: This will happen as long as the code runs in VBA. To get around this, you will need to create a program outside of Excel.You can try something like VB.Net or Python.